# Delayed Entry Reserves and Job Seeking

Tags: united-states, background-check, fraud

I am legally-speaking a servicemember. I am in the Delayed Entry Reserves, hence only *"legally-speaking."*

Several months ago, I went seeking a better career. I applied at several locations, and after no immediate luck, I tried enlisting in the USN.

There were medical and legal complications with the Navy that postponed my enlistment by months after beginning the enlistment process.

During that time, the company, I now work with, reviewed my application and had already gone through with interviewing me.

They hired, but after I had enlisted in Delayed Entry Reserves, and I took the job, because I was going to be in Delayed Entry for a while.

### TL;DR (my problem):

I discovered after telling my supervisor about my status, that my status as a servicemember didn't come up in my background check, and it wasn't on my application, because I had started the enlistment process after applying.

I am confused about my status.  Am I still required to serve in the navy? Is my new employer likely to take action against me if I do?

Comment: this would be a better fit for law.SE.

Comment: an important point to keep in mind is that random people on the internet are not your lawyers. You may wish to ask this on laws.SE however even there, people will only be able to give you a more on point opinion, not a verified anwser. If this is important and causes you a lot of problems you will want to consult a professional.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are not a service member yet. I know you took the oath etc, but until you actually show up for induction into service you are still completely civilian and can back out [with out any lasting repercussions beyond a potential barring from reenlistment.](https://girightshotline.org/en/military-knowledge-base/topic/delayed-entry-program-discharge-dep-discharge)

There are also [some protections](https://military-law.lawyers.com/military-law-basics/employer-obligations-to-military-employees.html) should you decide you want to continue with your enlistment, that may require your employer to hold your position for you.  I am not sure if you have been employed there long enough but should you choose to show up for induction, your company may keep your position open for when you exit service.